# Issue with using jQuery deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, deferred

I am using jQuery Deferred. I want to do 2 things when I click on a link to open modal dialog;

1. Call my API
2. Call my template (where values from API would get populated)

So I am doing the following;

```
self.myModel = new myModel();
self.myModel.url = "api/myModel/";

self.scenarioRecInfoDeferred = new $.Deferred();
self.myModel.fetch({
        success : function(){
            myModelDeferred.resolve();
        }
});


self.tmplDeferred = new $.Deferred();


$.when(self.myModelDeferred, self.tmplDeferred).done(function(modalTemplates) {
    
});

require(['text!templates/mytemp/my-tpl.html'], function(modalTemplates) {
    self.tmplDeferred.resolve(modalTemplates);
});
```

Now I am not getting anything for "modalTemplates" inside

```
$.when(self.myModelDeferred, self.tmplDeferred).done(function(modalTemplates) {}
```

Am I doing something wrong in accessing/passing the parameter?

Comment: What's the difference between `self.scenarioRecInfoDeferred`, `myModelDeferred` and `self.myModelDeferred`?

Comment: What is `self`? The global `window` object?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need 2 parameters in your `.done()` function handler. The first parameter will correspond to `myModelDeferred` arguments (which will be undefined) and the second will correspond to `tmplDeferred` arguments.

I made a quick jsfiddle to test myself.

```
var action1 = $.Deferred();
var action2 = $.Deferred();

setTimeout(function(){
    action1.resolve();
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    action2.resolve("def", "ghi");
}, 500);

$.when(action1.promise(), action2.promise()).done(function(args, args2){
    console.log(args);  // undefined
    console.log(args2); // ["def", "ghi"]
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/2ct6x/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to declare the deferred before loading the template?

You could do whatever you need to do with modalTemplates inside that require block and just skip the tmplDeferred use at all.

```
require(['text!templates/mytemp/my-tpl.html'], function(modalTemplates) {
    self.myModelDeferred.done(function(modalTemplates) {

    });

});
```

Anyway, if you want to stick to that structure, I don't think that's the way to pass a variable to a deferred. You could instead assign it as `self.tmplDeferred.modalTemplates=modalTemplates`. So, the next should work

```
$.when(self.myModelDeferred, self.tmplDeferred).done(function(self.tmplDeferred.modalTemplates) {

});

require(['text!templates/mytemp/my-tpl.html'], function(modalTemplates) {
    self.tmplDeferred.modalTemplates=modalTemplates;
    self.tmplDeferred.resolve();
});
```